# Autoversioning templateURL's in Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I'm having a major problem with Angular2 cacheing templateURL's on the production server.

What would be the easiest way to auto-version the .html template files like this:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'pricing-bar',
    templateUrl: './app/pricing-bar/pricing-bar.component.html?v=autoversionvariable',
})
```

I don't want to have to add the version every single time I make a change to the html templates, which is quite frequently.

It would be best if it was based on the last time the file was saved or modified so the user is always getting the latest version of the file.  If this file hasn't been changed it's fine to load from the cache.

Comment: First of all: How are you building for PRD? Are you bundling? Are you using WebPack, Gulp or SystemJS?

Comment: SystemJS is what's being used